# How to make qt applications to choose Regular style font by-Default?

Tags: gtk, qt, ubuntu-font-family

In modern Ubuntu versions (11.10, 12.04) there is an additional style for Ubuntu font called '*Medium*' it's slightly thicker than a '*Regular*' style user by default.

The problem is that all QT apps just suddenly start using that '*Medium*' style, instead of 
'*Regular*' which is used by default in all GTK apps.

How to fix this without removing `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-M*.ttf` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is:

- [Bug #744812](http://launchpad.net/bugs/744812) *("FontConfig/Qt stack choke on Ubuntu Medium font meta-data (No medium in Inkscape and too bold in Qt apps)")*

Answer (score 0):

Install the `qt4-qtconfig` package, should be able to adjust fonts for you as desired

Comment: Not making any difference here in 12.04.

Comment: Same, I change the settings but they don't seem to be saved.